# Criar arquivos na pasta Home com C++

Tags: c++, linux, arquivo

Em c++, criar arquivos é muito simples, basta incluir a biblioteca fstream e usar

```
ofstream arquivo;
```

arquivo.open("variaveis.txt");

Porém isso gera o arquivo na pasta do projeto e eu gostaria de gerar o arquivo em alguma outra pasta, como a Área de trabalho por exemplo. Só que existe um pequeno problema nesses casos, em cada computador com linux o caminho para a Área de trabalho é diferente. No meu por exemplo eu poderia simplesmente fazer isso:

```
iofstream arquivo;
arquivo.open("/home/silas/desktop/arquivo.txt");
```

Mas em outro computador talvez seja:

```
iofstream arquivo;
arquivo.open("/home/lucas/desktop/arquivo.txt");
```

Uma possível solução poderia ser usar o

```
system("whoami");
```

Que escreve no terminal o nome do usuario,porem não conheço nenhuma maneira de colocar o resultado do comando para uma string. Então, existe alguma maneira de fazer isso ? Ou pelo menos alguma função que retorne o usuário do sistema, isso já ajudaria muito.

Comment: Porque não usa `~/desktop/arquivo.txt` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depende do que você precisa fazer. A variável de ambiente `HOME` pode ser manipulada pelo usuário permitindo que um lugar falso seja especificado. Para obter o home verdadeiro você pode usar a função `getpwuid`. Para obter o home que o usuário quiser lhe informar use a `getenv`.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main( void )
{
  uid_t uid = getuid();
  cout << "UID: " << uid << endl;
  cout << "HOME(real): " << getpwuid( uid )->pw_dir << endl;
  cout << "HOME(root): " << getpwuid( 0 )->pw_dir << endl;
  cout << "HOME(env): " << getenv( "HOME" ) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

A saída do programa acima, para um home forçado pode ser:

```
$ HOME="/tmp/xyz" ./a.out 

UID: 1001
HOME(real): /home/intmain/geraldoim
HOME(root): /root
HOME(env): /tmp/xyz
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode uasr a função getenv() para obter o valor de $HOME:

```
const char* s = getenv("HOME");
```

Comment: Só lembrar que é da `cstdlib` essa função

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário, até achei que era algo POSIX-apenas